# MVC View adding in quotations to html attribute

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a small project and in the partial navigation view I am checking if a page is selected and highlighting the menu.

```
var controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower();

var home = string.Empty;
var content = string.Empty;

switch(controller) {
    case "home":
        home = "class=current";
        break; 
    case "content":
        content = "class=current";
        break;  
}
```

In the view I am then doing:

```
<li @home><a href="/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
```

Originally in my code I had

```
home = "class='current'";
```

Notice I had quotations around it, but when I executed the code the html source looks like

[image]

So when I remove the quatations and run it again, since it's adding them in by default, it works, even though the debugger looks like

[image]

So the project is working, my question is why is it by default adding in the quotations?

Comment: Because `home` is a variable of type string?

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: My question isn't targeted at a solution, it's targeted at an explanation to why it's doing this, I already have it working, I just want to know why it's doing what it's doing

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that MVC is adding the quotes, that is probably the Chrome DevTools doing it. If you "View page source", I don't think you will see the quotes.

Just FYI, because of these kinds of things I usually don't include the attribute in such strings, just the value...

```
<li class="@home">
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC doesn't add quotes for `@home`. If you decompile this page, you could get codes like below:

```
    public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : WebViewPage<object>
    {
        // Methods
        public override void Execute()
        {
            ((dynamic) base.ViewBag).Title = "Home Page";
            base.BeginContext("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", 0x27, 2, true);
            this.WriteLiteral("\r\n");
            base.EndContext("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", 0x27, 2, true);
            string str = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            string str2 = string.Empty;
            string str3 = string.Empty;
            string str4 = str;
            if (str4 != null)
            {
                if (!(str4 == "Home"))
                {
                    if (str4 == "content")
                    {
                        str3 = "class=current";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    str2 = "class=current";
                }
            }
            base.BeginContext("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", 0x1a6, 9, true);
            this.WriteLiteral("\r\n\r\n<div ");
            base.EndContext("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", 0x1a6, 9, true);
            base.BeginContext("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", 0x1b0, 4, false);
            this.Write(str2);
....
}
}
```

The Write methods will finally calls [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebUtility.cs) method, this method replaces special chars, but will not add quotes.

Hope this helps.